# Swift: CoreImage Face Detection will Detect Every round object as a Face

Tags: ios, swift4, core-image

In my app, I want to use face detection for UIImage so I use **CoreImage** build in Library(I know that Vision Library is the newest Library for Face Detection too. But it supports only for ios 11.0 and above). The library is working fine until I notice somethings that any image with a round surface will be detected as a face even it's not.

Here is my code:

```
func checkFaceDetection(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
        var isFace = false
        let personciImage = CIImage(image: image)

        let accuracy = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
        let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: accuracy)
        let faces = faceDetector?.features(in: personciImage!)

        if let face = faces?.first as? CIFaceFeature {
            print("Found face at \(face.bounds)")
            if face.hasLeftEyePosition && face.hasRightEyePosition && face.hasMouthPosition && face.hasFaceAngle{
                isFace = true
            }else{
                isFace = false
            }
        }
        return isFace
    }
```

***Even i filter that image with lefteye,righteye,mouth and faceAngle, it's still can't solve my problem.***

Comment: any sample image where it fails ?

Comment: i don't really know how to show you by image because it's not an error but a bug because the function that i shown above is always return true if my sample image contain round object or circle. **it's should return true only if it found left eye, right eye, mouth and faceAngle altogether**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the CIDetectorAccuracyHigh to Low instead. it would be more usable

Answer (score -1):

let imageOptions =  NSDictionary(object: NSNumber(value: 5) as NSNumber, forKey: CIDetectorImageOrientation as NSString)

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually provide an answer to the question.